# In the OpenFDA database, is trade name the same as brand name?

Tags: openfda

i wanted to get the trade name of a drug, but in https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.generic_name:Amoxicillin i get brand_name.
so can someone please confirm, that brand_name refers to trade name?
Because as per above link, generic_name and brand_name are same.

Comment: It is possible that, for drugs that have been generic for a long time, the brand name, trade name and generic name are the same. Try checking whether the names are the same for recent drugs still on patent.